# Can't get IF statement to work in Javascript with a counting timer

Tags: javascript, random, timer

I am trying to make this IF statement work.  I have spent hours struggling today.  The idea here, is that my program will pick a random number.  (between 1 and 5)  There is a counter that starts at zero, and when it hits this random number it will alert me a text description. I also am trying to get it to play a sound (just a square wave) but now I have that commented out because I can't even get it to display the text when the timer reaches the random number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Javascript CART breakdown calculator</h2>

<button onclick="pause_function()">pause</button>
<button onclick="resume_speed_function()">resume</button>


<label id="seconds">0</label>
<p id="random_number_display"></p>
<p id="breakdown_item"></p>


<script>

var my_random_number, low, high;
low = 1;
high = 5;
my_random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * high) + low;
document.getElementById("random_number_display").innerHTML = my_random_number;

var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

var random_breakdown_event, low_event, high_event;
low_event = 1
high_event = 9
random_breakdown_event = Math.floor(Math.random() * high_event) + low_event;
var text

if (random_breakdown_event == 1) text = "blown engine";
if (random_breakdown_event == 2) text = "broken transmission";
if (random_breakdown_event == 3) text = "broken suspension";
if (random_breakdown_event == 4) text = "broken halfshaft";
if (random_breakdown_event == 5) text = "broken cv joint";
if (random_breakdown_event == 6) text = "broken wings";
if (random_breakdown_event == 7) text = "electrical misfire";
if (random_breakdown_event == 8) text = "broken fuel pump";
if (random_breakdown_event == 9) text = "change battery";

var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
var interval_between_ticks = 1000;
//Assign the interval to a variable to keep track of it
var interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);

function setTime() {
++totalSeconds;
secondsLabel.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
}

function  pause_function() {
interval_between_ticks = 999999999;
//Clear the old interval so we don't have memory leaks
clearInterval(interval);
//Set the interval with the new time between clicks
interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);
}

function  resume_speed_function() {
interval_between_ticks = 1000;
//Clear the old interval so we don't have memory leaks
clearInterval(interval);
//Set the interval with the new time between clicks
interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);
}


if(my_random_number==totalSeconds){
document.getElementById("breakdown_item").innerHTML = text}

//if(my_random_number>=4){
//function myFunction(frequency, duration, callback) {
//    duration = 10000 / 1000;     // the 10000 used to be 'duration' 
//    oscillator.type = 'square';
//    oscillator.frequency.value = 500; // value in hertz
//   oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
//    oscillator.onended = callback;
//    oscillator.start(0);
//    oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + duration);
//}


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: declaring a function in an if statement doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: what is the correct way to do this?  I have pieced this together by modifying examples and asking for help.

Comment: Declaring a function is just that, you're creating it, but not executing. Just like your function `resume_speed_function` is declared, but not actually executed until your button press calls it. The correct thing to do is declare the function at the top of the script, and then call it by name `myFunction(args)` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vMZvmW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the if block inside the **setTime** function.

In your original implementation the equality check between my_random_number and totalSeconds is gonna execute only the first time when the script executes. But it should check the equality every time the number of seconds is increased which is the setTime function. The code below should work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Javascript CART breakdown calculator</h2>

<button onclick="pause_function()">pause</button>
<button onclick="resume_speed_function()">resume</button>


<label id="seconds">0</label>
<p id="random_number_display"></p>
<p id="breakdown_item"></p>


<script>

var my_random_number, low, high;
low = 1;
high = 5;
my_random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * high) + low;
document.getElementById("random_number_display").innerHTML = my_random_number;

var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

var random_breakdown_event, low_event, high_event;
low_event = 1
high_event = 9
random_breakdown_event = Math.floor(Math.random() * high_event) + low_event;
var text

if (random_breakdown_event == 1) text = "blown engine";
if (random_breakdown_event == 2) text = "broken transmission";
if (random_breakdown_event == 3) text = "broken suspension";
if (random_breakdown_event == 4) text = "broken halfshaft";
if (random_breakdown_event == 5) text = "broken cv joint";
if (random_breakdown_event == 6) text = "broken wings";
if (random_breakdown_event == 7) text = "electrical misfire";
if (random_breakdown_event == 8) text = "broken fuel pump";
if (random_breakdown_event == 9) text = "change battery";

var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
var interval_between_ticks = 1000;
//Assign the interval to a variable to keep track of it
var interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
  if (my_random_number == totalSeconds) {
    document.getElementById("breakdown_item").innerHTML = text;
  }
}

function  pause_function() {
interval_between_ticks = 999999999;
//Clear the old interval so we don't have memory leaks
clearInterval(interval);
//Set the interval with the new time between clicks
interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);
}

function  resume_speed_function() {
interval_between_ticks = 1000;
//Clear the old interval so we don't have memory leaks
clearInterval(interval);
//Set the interval with the new time between clicks
interval = setInterval(setTime, interval_between_ticks);
}

//if(my_random_number>=4){
//function myFunction(frequency, duration, callback) {
//    duration = 10000 / 1000;     // the 10000 used to be 'duration' 
//    oscillator.type = 'square';
//    oscillator.frequency.value = 500; // value in hertz
//   oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
//    oscillator.onended = callback;
//    oscillator.start(0);
//    oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + duration);
//}


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have explained the reason in the answer. Is it not clear?

Comment: I see what you mean, I need to study it more.   Javascript is really difficult for me.  I am completely new at this and have only messed with programming excel macros.  I am trying to implement the sound portion of it now.  Thank you for your help you got me one step closer.

Comment: @djturbojp7 If my answer solved your problem then could you mark it as accepted. Thank you.